# Excel Pain: Saved With Filters, Opened And file Was Half the Size

Tags: excel

So something happened twice that has caused me hours of retroactive work. Extremely, extremely annoying, and the bain of my existence.

I have an .xls file with about 171K rows. I saved it with filters on, reducing the number of shown rows to about 13K. When I reopened the file the next day the filters were not showing, but rows were 'hidden', because in order to show all the rows I had to 'unhide'. The problem is that when I unhide, the total rows is ~65K aka the last numbered row that was showing when I had filters on.

Has this happened to anyone before or know how to recover the full 171K rows? I know for a fact I didn't 'clear' or 'delete' anything before or after saving.

Comment: This is because `XLS` files are limited to 65,536 rows. Anything below that was removed. The solution is to save the file as `XLSX`

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad This is news to me, thank you. So no way to recover?

Answer (score 1):

One piece of advise I have is for you to start reading screen prompts.  When saving a large file with over 65536 rows this kind of warning is displayed.  Only you can prevent your own errors.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this by making a **copy** of the original and filtering on that, then you always have the source if you make an error.